# ProcessRequest from RequestInterceptor never ends [WCF]

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-starting-guide

So, I'm using the [Developer's Guide to the WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) and having a problem with the RequestInterceptor. I have the exact code the guide is showing but for some reason the method never ends.

This is my code:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(ref RequestContext requestContext)
{
   GenerateErrorResponse(requestContext, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "shit happens!");
}

public void GenerateErrorResponse(RequestContext context, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string errorMessage)
{
   XElement response = XElement.Load(new StringReader(string.Format(ERROR_HTML, errorMessage)));

   Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "action", response);
   HttpResponseMessageProperty responseProp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty()
   {
      StatusCode = statusCode,
      //StatusDescription = errorMessage
   };
   responseProp.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
   reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = responseProp;
   context.Reply(reply);

   context = null;
 }
```

My call gets stuck at context.Reply(reply); I have no idea what I'm doing wrong... any heads up?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my bad... it was a simple/stupid issue.
First of all there was an Exception taking place that I was not seeing... once I added a try catch and tracing I discovered I was getting the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: This collection holds request headers and cannot contain the specified response header".

After looking a little closer I noticed I was adding a HttpRequestHeader instead of the HttpResponseHeader... my bad :(

```
responseProp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
```